# Create Login in Azure Sql db with EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE or any other way

Tags: azure, sqldb

USE statement is not supported in azure sql db. I want to create new login in master db from another database (for ex. Abc Database). Please let me know how i can achieve this.

[Error ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GX8mO.png)

Comment: So you 're trying to do cross database query ?

Comment: Yes. Cross Database query to create the login in master table first and then add that particular user in the second database

Comment: I don't understand, why  my question has  downvoted

Comment: Try to explain what you're trying to do, is it not easy to understand at the moment.

Comment: You can have a look at this article: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/querying-remote-databases-in-azure-sql-db/

Comment: @Thomas Thank you for your reply !! I have already seen this article. This Article tells about how the do the cross database Query (to either fetch or save the data). But My requirement is to create the  new Login User into the master database from some another database in Azure. I have added "Error Screenshot" in Question. Please do let me know if need anything from my side.  I already seen these type of links (https://www.sqlnethub.com/blog/creating-azure-sql-database-logins-and-users/) but these links are not helpful . Reason is , i am calling the Stored procedure from Asp.net core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve the problem by changing the database connection string from my code.
Because "***USE statement***" is not supported in azure sql db , i need to change lot of code. So i hope USE statement will come ASAP in azure.